# Understanding a general statement

Tags: meaning

"**Sexual inactivity or inexperience**, whether voluntary or not, **should not be** exoticized, ridiculed, or **necessarily considered a concern for everyone**. More research is needed on reasons for sexual inactivity and how mating market dynamics might be evolving due to online dating, shifting expectations in romantic and sexual relationships, and changing values, lifestyles, and labor market trends," said Dr. Peter Ueda, an expert in epidemiology and public health and leader of the research project.

Does "everyone" refer to the aforesaid group or to the general public?

[Sexual inactivity in Japan](https://www.forbes.com/sites/ericmack/2019/04/07/a-quarter-of-japanese-adults-under-40-are-virgins-and-the-number-is-increasing/#3caabac87e4d)

Comment: It probably means all the people in the vicinity who might have some awareness or interest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we have no idea where this sentence came from.  So, we can't give a definitive answer.

Comment: Hi Labory. It's unclear what is meant. Where was the group mentioned? More context would help. Can you give us a longer excerpt?

Comment: everyone: "the general public" in the context. (think: "should not be ...." by whom?)

Comment: Folks, Everything is very much there, look carefully. Good Luck.

Comment: The start of the quote is given here. No 'aforesaid group' is referenced by Dr. Peter Ueda. (I do think, though, that the article sacrifices clarity for style).

Comment: But is the above expression rational? It suggests the public should not presuppose that sexual inactivity or inexperience concerns the public.

Comment: @Labory We are not here to critique texts or do interpretations. This site focuses on English as a language, like syntax, morphology, orthography, phonology, etc. not content. This text could be written in Vietnamese and you’d have the same question about the *content*.